# Data sets for realistic random/test data generation

Tags: random, dataset

Where to get data sets for random or test data generation, such as names/surnames with distribution, address data, university/school names, company names etc.?

I've found the list of English names and surnames, with the count of them (unfortunately I haven't noted from where I got that). I got address database from Poland.  However these data sets from other countries would also be very useful for me. So with university and school names.

What data do you need as source for such information? Could you provide links to such data? (of course, only those who are free publicly available)

Comment: I'm flagging this question because it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will find answer to your question in following topics:

[Sample database for exercise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719259/sample-database-for-exercise)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202092/where-can-i-find-free-and-open-data

Answer (score 4):

There are many open source and commericial test data generators on internet. Below 2 are good ones

1. http://www.sqledit.com/dg/
2. http://www.generatedata.com/#about
3. for random numbers/strings: http://www.random.org/

Comment: The second link is quite good, it contains some data I need but I still would like to have broader data sets. First is commercial and second is full random only.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon has made several public data sets available for free download:
http://aws.amazon.com/publicdatasets/

Comment: I was trying, but couldn't find the download link on that page

Answer (score 2):

Try http://www.mockaroo.com

You can generate up to 100,000 rows of data in CSV, tab-delimited and SQL formats, save & reuse schemas, and automate test data generation using curl.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free API at http://randomprofile.com/api-for-developers/ for generating test user profiles which include name, surname, address, bank info, CC number, blood type etc. Not sure about the schools, but useful if you're looking after data on Asian users.