# Sample sql product Data

Tags: sql, product

Looking for a open source range of data. Needs to be a range of products with variations e.g. books, shoes, hats, cds, dvds, dog toys, you get the idea, random products.

Also needs to be for a sql database.

Anybody got any suggestions where I might find such data?

Comment: You can talk randomly to any shop that sell hats, cds, dvds, dog toys, books shoes... see if they can share...in a union... sorry

Comment: Have you checked out Amazon?

Comment: Are you looking for [sample databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719259/sample-database-for-exercise)? or some specific sample data like the examples you posted in your questions?

Comment: I have a database, i am looking for sample data to populate it with, in the process of building a collaborative filtering system and need sample data to test it with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a search for Northwind database samples.  Microsoft also has some free database setups to us for practice.  You can download these from their website.